# Correct steps in rewriting expectation to a probability

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, markov-process

My knowledge of measure theory and probability spaces is limited, so please keep it relatively simple.

Let $\{X(t), ~ t \ge 0\}$ be a Markov process on the countable state space $\mathbb{N}_0$ with initial condition $X(0) = 0$. Let $T_j$ be the first time the Markov process hits state $j$.

Say I want to compute the expected time spent in state $i$ before I reach state $j$, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{t = 0}^\infty 1\{X(t) = i, T_j > t\} \,\mathrm{d}t \right], \tag 1
\end{equation}

where $1\{\cdot\}$ is the indicator function. I would like to write that $(1)$ is equal to

\begin{equation}
\int_{t = 0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X(t) = i, T_j > t) \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag 2
\end{equation}

However, I am unsure about what the correct mathematical steps are and what notation I should use. So, my question is, is the following correct and what notation should be improved upon?

My attempt is as follows

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{t = 0}^\infty 1\{X(t) = i, T_j > t\} \,\mathrm{d}t \right] &= \int_{\omega \in \Omega} \int_{t = 0}^\infty 1\{X(t,\omega) = i, T_j(\omega) > t\} \,\mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) \\
&= \int_{t = 0}^\infty \int_{\omega \in \Omega} 1\{X(t,\omega) = i, T_j(\omega) > t\} \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{t = 0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X(t) = i, T_j > t) \, \mathrm{d}t,
\end{align}

where $\omega$ is an outcome,  $\Omega$ is the sample space and $\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ is the probability of outcome $\omega$ and I use Tonelli's theorem for the second equality. By outcome I mean a sample path of the Markov process.

Comment: Your argumentation is correct.

Comment: @saz Thank you for your comment. This is probabily unrelated, but I might as well ask: I have heard others saying that you could also express the expected value as an integral over all events in the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$. How would that work in the case above?

Comment: An integral over all events? This sounds rather odd to me... So, sorry, I don't know what they were talking about.

Comment: @saz That sounds like a relief, haha. So it isn't only me that did not understand it.